# Is it possible to put a `\begin{itemize}` block inside a macro?

Tags: macros

I'm writing a test and I have a lot of true/false questions. So I tried the obvious macro:

```
\newcommand{truefalse}{
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item True
        \item False
    \end{itemize}
}
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

- Missing \begin{document}. }
- Missing number, treated as zero. }
- Missing control sequence inserted. }
- You already have nine parameters. }

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? Preferably with as few dependencies as possible -- I'm working on a system where I can't easily download new packages. Thank you!

Comment: Aren't you missing a ``\`` in that macron name or is it a typo?

Comment: With the backslash at the beginning of the command, it works fine.

Comment: Thank you both. I was indeed missing a backslash. If either of you feel like making your comment an answer, I'll accept the first one :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a typo.